# Problem with Rubi` and paclets in Version 12.1?

Tags: paclets, version-12.1, rubi

A recent Quora post on [computing an integral](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-value-of-the-integral-displaystyle-int_-0-1-ln-1-x-ln-1-x-dx) used the [Integral Calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com), the interface and display of which I found somewhat impressive. So I thought that I'd try the same computation in [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org/integrationRules.html) so as to compare the functionality and format.

Before getting started, I checked whether I had installed the latest version, which is 4.16.1.0 (which led me to making a suggestion on GitHub to the developers about automating this). I needed to update, so I executed the following code:

```
PacletUninstall["Rubi"]

PacletInstall["https://github.com/RuleBasedIntegration/Rubi/releases/download/\
    4.16.1.0/Rubi-4.16.1.0.paclet"]

path = First[PacletFind["Rubi"]]["Location"]

Get["Rubi`"]
```

However, this immediately results in a number of error messages of the type

```
LoadRules::inv: Could not load file or section:
    {/Users/paul/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/Rubi-4.16.1.0/IntegrationRules/\
     9 Miscellaneous\9.1 Integrand simplification rules.m}
```

etc. Is this a known problem?

Modifying the steps above to load the *previous* paclet that I'd installed (4.16.0.4), appeared to work fine. And I could generate the steps in the computation of the indefinite integral

```
Steps @ Int[Log[1-x] Log[1+x],x]
```

which have some advantages, and some disadvantages when compared to the [Integral Calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com).

However, there is one weird issue that I cannot track down: Using paclet loading (as above) I get a *different* output for `Information[Steps]` to what I get if I load the paclet *manually*: For some reason, the paclet-loaded version has `Removed[Int]` instead of `Int`. And *manual* loading of the current version does not work at all.

Comment: `so I executed the following code:` why did y not use what it says at https://rulebasedintegration.org/downloadRubi.html which is `PacletInstall["https://rulebasedintegration.org/Rubi-4.16.1.0.paclet"]` ? This is the command I used and it worked ok for me, but I am on windows. V 12.1. it looks like you are on Linux system. fyi, The expert in issues with Rubi installations is Halirutan.

Comment: Can you try ``<<Rubi` `` again after restarting the kernel?

Comment: I'll have a look at it, but atm I have so many side-projects that I could easily stop working my real job :)
Would anyone, who is in the best case also using Rubi regularly, be up to join maintaining the project? This would include taking care of building the paclet from Alberts integration rules.

Comment: To @Nasser, I didn't make up the `PacletInstall` command I used. It was in the instructions (which appear to have been updated/corrected now).

Comment: To @Szabolcs: I did multiple kernel restarts. But using `PacletInstall["https://rulebasedintegration.org/Rubi-4.16.1.0.paclet"]` seems to work fine—so I am wondering if there was a problem with the GitHub paclet (which does seem strange)...

Comment: The GitHub paclet worked fine for me after a kernel restart (before that I saw the same error as you), but I didn't investigate deeply ...

Answer (score 6):

Here is what's happening: Albert uploaded a new 4.16.1.0 paclet to the website where the necessary fix of using `FileNameJoin` is already included. These changes were not backported to the GitHub repository and this is why you get the error with the same paclet version from the GitHub releases.

The solution is to use the installation instructions as given on the Rubi website

```
PacletInstall["https://rulebasedintegration.org/Rubi-4.16.1.0.paclet"]
```

Comment: One suggestion: instead of including the version number with the paclet name—and since when you load the paclet the version number is returned—why not just change the install to `PacletInstall["https://rulebasedintegration.org/Rubi.paclet"]` so that one can automatically install the latest version. One could, of course, load a specific version, if required, but most times one just wants to be sure to be using the latest version.

Comment: My response won't fit in a single comment. I moved this conversation [to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107855/discussion-on-answer-by-halirutan-problem-with-rubi-and-paclets-in-version-12-1).